# react-native-dotenv with multiple enviorments only runs local env in react native using typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, environment, dotenv

i'm trying to expo start my react native with typescript app on 3 different environments-
development, local and testing. but when i run `APP_ENV=testing expo start` or `APP_ENV=development expo start` it always runs on local environment.
i tried using `APP_ENV=testing expo r -c` or `APP_ENV=development expo r -c`
and `yarn start --reset-cache` and react-native-clean-project and non of those helped.
in the root of my project i have a folder named "environments" with 4 files- ".env.local", ".env.development", ".env.testing" and "types.d.ts". this is the code containd in my "babel.config.js"-

```
 api.cache(true);
 return {
   presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
   plugins: [
     "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
     [
       "module:react-native-dotenv",
       {
         moduleName: "react-native-dotenv",
         path: "./environments/.env",
         blacklist: null,
         whitelist: null,
         safe: false,
         allowUndefined: true,
       },
     ],
   ],
 };
};
```

this is the code containd in types.d.ts file from environments folder- `declare module "react-native-dotenv" { export const API_BASE_URL: string; }`

i also added the following `"typesRootes": ["./environments/types"]` to "tsconfig.json"

im really not sure how to solve this, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using env names such as `development`, `production`, and `test`, you do not need `APP_ENV` and should not use `APP_ENV`. just use `NODE_ENV`. Also, if you are using `APP_ENV`, avoid using `development`, `production`, and `test`. - `react-native-dotenv` maintainer